# Debian 10 network configuration not applied on boot or link reset

Tags: networking, vlan, debian-buster

I am missing something on a Debian 10 server: my network configuration is not applied on reboot or after the link is reset.

In my case, the server has two interface: `eno3` (public) and `eno4` (private). The `eno3` interface is configured via DHCP. The `eno4` is configured manually and is set for use in a VLAN.

To configure the private interface, the following commands were applied.

```
 $ sudo apt-get install vlan
 $ vconfig add eno4 3
 $ ip addr add 172.16.2.0/24 dev eno4.3
 $ ifconfig eno4.3 172.16.2.101 netmask 255.255.255.0
 $ ip link set dev eno4 up
```

This makes the network work correctly. To make the configuration persistant, I created the following files :

`/etc/systemd/network/eno4.3.netdev`

```
[NetDev]
Name=eno4.3
Kind=vlan

[VLAN]
Id=3
```

`/etc/systemd/network/eno4.network`

```
[Match]
MACAddress=ac:1f:6b:xx:xx:xx (with real network adapter MAC instead of XX)

[Network]
Description=network interface on vrack network, with default route
VLAN=eno4.3
```

`/etc/systemd/network/eno4.3.network`
[Match]
Name=eno4.3

```
[Network]
Description="VLAN 3"
Address=172.16.2.1/24
```

I am not really sure this is the right way to do for this Debian 10 server as I also noticed some files are created in `/etc/network/interfaces.d`, for instance `50-cloud-init`.